# How do you truncate elements of an array responsively?

Tags: javascript, frontend, truncate

I am trying to responsively truncate elements that do not fit in a table cell.

```
let names = ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'Elizabeth Hendrickson', 'Simon James']
```

The result looks something like this

John Doe,Jane Doe,Elizab...

And, if I make the browser smaller, it looks something like this

John Doe,Jane Do...

This is the CSS I used

```
.names {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I do not want to display Elizab or Jane Do in the examples. What I want to see instead is

John Doe,Jane Doe,...

OR

John Doe,...

Comment: If you need more information, please tell me. Thank you!

Comment: word-wrap:break-word perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to have an outside element, that has overflow: auto; and a specified width. It cant be a percentage for ellipsis to work. If you need it to be responsive, you must use javascript and listen for resize. Something like

```
  <div style="width: 100px;overflow: auto">
    <div class="names">

    </div>
  </div>
```